# Error al Crear Funcion Definida en Sql Server

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Logre que visualizara el nombre, pero aun no logro concatenar el apellido junto con el nombre, no lo entiendo si le estoy pasando la funcion concat, porque no concatena?, estoy usando la version sql server 2014.

```
La funcion es la siguiente:

        Create Function FullName (@FullName Varchar (50))
        Returns Varchar (50)

        As
       Begin

    select @Fullname=(concat(FirstName,' ',LastName)) from DimCustomer where 
    (concat(FirstName,' ',LastName))<>null

    Return @Fullname
    End


    Go
```

Comment: Hola amigo es que asi como lo tienes te devolvera mas de un registro no te hace falta un where ???? y la variable @Minombre no veo que la uses

Comment: ¿Que es lo que buscas con esta función? ¿Que te retorne un solo valor? ¿Que te te retorne múltiples? ¿Para que está el parámetro @Minombre?

Comment: Mientras la tabla DimCustomer tenga más de 1 registro, con la consulta actual, ocurrirá este error. Para asignar a una variable escalar el resultado de un `select`, este tiene que devolver una fila, no varias. Ya que haces un `select` sin `where` este devolverá tantas filas como filas tenga la tabla.

Comment: al parecer el resultado de la consulta es mas de un registro, agregale un distinct si es que son iguales o un condicional.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta, amplia por favor y explica

Comment: Sigues estando en un error amigo , que es lo que deseas regresar exactamente.... entiendo que el nombre de la persona pero con base a que lo quires regresar o quieres una lista de todos los nombres?

Comment: @EdgarVazquez en que me estoy equivocando, por fa ayuda,

Comment: @RicardoRoa lee los comentarios arriba pero con la nueva query que agregas confundes, diga que es lo que esperas de esa Query un ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Comment: @RicardoRoa esperas devolver el usuario pero como piensas buscarlo o quieres devolver una lista de todos los nombre que es lo que necesitas?

Comment: devolver una lista de todos los nombres  y apellidos concatenados @EdgarVazquez

Comment: De ser asi no seria mejor hacer una vista y consultas esa vista desde un select o simplemente hacer ese select dentro de un sp cual sera la funcionalidad de esa lista?

Comment: @EdgarVazquez por que no concatena, en que me estoy equivocando.

Comment: Que te muestra? que version de sql tienes?

Comment: @EdgarVazquez hay esta el resultado de lo que me muestra en la imagen

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96943/discussion-between-edgar-vazquez-and-ricardo-roa).

Comment: @EdgarVazquez ni asi como proposiste funciona , no se si sera alguna configuracion de sql server version 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realice esta Funcion y funciono.

```
CREATE FUNCTION THISNAME (@GEOGRAPHYKEY INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @MINAME NVARCHAR(50)
SELECT @MINAME=(FIRSTNAME+' '+LASTNAME) FROM DIMCUSTOMER
   WHERE GeographyKey=@GEOGRAPHYKEY
     RETURN @MINAME 
END

GO
```